Strategy Tradingview without Exit Trade
I'm new to TradingView. 
I found a tradingview strategy, but no take profit and stop loss price. I've learned that on TradingView, follow FIFO signals. If the first open signal is always open, a new signal will show again, and the previous one is closed.
if I connect TradingView using an API to a broker and use that strategy. Will my trade close too after a new signal appears on the chart, like on backtesting TradingView? Or should I add TakeProfit and Stoploss to each new signal?
